# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{n^{2}+5n}}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{n^{2}+5n}}$$

in order to simplify the expression I rationalised the denominator and got :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1+\sqrt{n^{2}+5n}}{1-{n^{2}-5n}}$$

This is where I stuck...

I can't use any of the convergence tests because the series itself is not positive.
How can I determine if the series is convergent or divergent?

Answer (score 3):

Your series converges if and only if the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+5n}-1}$$(which is your series times $-1$) converges, and *this* series happens to be a series of positive numbers. Furthermore,$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+5n}-1}}{\frac1n}=1.$$Therefore, your series diverges.

Comment: Sure: I am comparing the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+5n}-1}$ with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$, which diverges.

Answer (score 2):

We can use there asymptotic condition which states that if $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \rightarrow g $ where $ g \in \mathbb R \setminus \left\{ 0 \right\} $ then $\sum a_n$ diverges if and only if $\sum b_n$ diverges.
You see that in denominator you have
 $$1-\sqrt{n^{2}+5n} $$
which is similar to $n$, is that right? To be sure you can do asymptotic test:
$$ \frac{1-\sqrt{n^{2}+5n}}{n} = \frac{1}{n} - \sqrt{\frac{n^2+5n}{n^2}} \rightarrow 0 - 1 = -1$$
so due to $$ \sum \frac{1}{n} $$ diverges, your series diverges too.